# Pigeonhole Principle and its relation to Functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Generally the pigeonhole principle is formulated as follows

> If there are $m$ pigeons and $n$ holes, such that $m>n$, then there must exist at least one hole that shares more than $1$ pigeon

However this seems to just be a fairly direct consequence of injective functions. i.e.

> Let $P$ be the set of pigeons and $H$ the set of holes, with $|P|>|H|$. $\forall f:P\rightarrow H$, $f$ is not injective

Is this an ok way to think about the pigeonhole principle, or is there more to it that I am missing?

Comment: This is equivalent to saying if we have more pigeons than holes, then we cannot have a mapping of pigeons to holes where each hole contains exactly one pigeon. You are taking the pigeonhole principle and applying it to functions between sets of finite sizes.

Comment: Could this idea that no injective mapping exists if the cardinality is strictly greater apply to infinite sets as well, or is that circular reasoning (ie in order to show the cardinality is greater you must show prior there is no injective mapping)

Comment: This is actually the definition. For *any* two sets $A$ and $B$, finite or infinite, we say that $|A| \le |B|$ if an injective function exists going from $A$ to $B$. See [Cardinality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20cardinality%20of,has%20a%20cardinality%20of%203.)

Comment: As for your question, no you are not missing anything. The pigeonhole principle is just a colloquial way of saying the injective function idea. By their tees almost everybody will understand the pigeonhole principle, but the vast majority of people are not going to understand "injective function".